# The application is running twice in production mode with UWSGI and Flask (tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask)

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am using tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6 image with Docker.

The app is running twice in production mode. I've set DEBUG = False and ENV = 'production' in config.py as well as I've set FLASK_DEBUG = 0 in docker environment. I am running in production and not using app.run method. My main.py is something like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
print('*** HELLO WORLD ***')
```

The print statement is printing twice. I understand the reloader is used in Debug mode in Flask, but I've tried to disable Debug mode in every way. Is this something related to the current image I am using?

Comment: How are you running it? What are the commands? What is the full `config.py`?

Comment: This is being run through uwsgi and nginx. I am using the docker to run it using this image tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask.

Comment: Show us how you are starting it; thats the key here. You sure this is not a problem related to this->https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/uwsgi/

Comment: I asked how it was started because many WSGI servers will start multiple workers with the default based on your CPU count. I'm guessing you are starting this on a Docker host that has two CPU or two cores and uwsgi is defaulting to two workers, thus showing your print startup message twice.